# Check if property is not undefined

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I'm building a node+express app and I'm filling an object with JSON that's submitted from a form in the frontend. This works, unless I leave a field empty in the form so that e.g. req.body.address.street is empty/undefined.

This will result in the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'street' of undefined

var b = new Business({
        name: req.body.name,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        address: {
            street: req.body.address.street,
            postalCode: req.body.address.postalCode,
            city: req.body.address.city
        },
        owner: {
            email: req.body.owner.email,
            password: req.body.owner.password
        }
    });
```

My question is how I can best prevent my app from crashing when values are empty. I would like to avoid manually checking each and every property in my app against undefined.

I'm wondering what the best practice is for this common issue.

Comment: Perhaps defining an object with a default for each property, then `b` can extend from the default object?

Comment: It's not `street` that is undefined but `req.body.address`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, really. You have two options;

Use a try/ catch:

```
try {
    var b = new Business({
        // 
    });
} catch (e) {
    // Something wasn't provided.
}
```

... or you can define a helper function:

```
function get(path, obj) {
    path = path.split('.');
    path.shift(); // Remove "req".

    while (path.length && obj.hasOwnProperty(path[0])) {
        obj = obj[path.shift()];
    }

    return !path.length ? obj : null;
}
```

... you could then replace your use of `req.body.address.street` etc. with `get('req.body.address.street', req)`.

See a demo here; http://jsfiddle.net/W8YaB/

Comment: Thanks, this would have worked. In the end I decided it would be a lot easier to just simplify my POST payload and avoid this kind of behaviour altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you use jQuery in your project, but if you do, you can create a mask:

```
// creating your object mask
var req = {
    body: {
        name: '',
        phone: '',
        address: {
            street: '',
            postalCode: '',
            city: ''
        },
        owner: {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }
    }
}
```

And then, you simply use the [jQuery "extend" method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) (req2 is your submmited object):

```
$.extend(true, req, req2);
```

I've create [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8bJ7/) for you!

#### -

#### Update

Nothing related to your question, but I've just noticed that you're passing an object with a similar structure of req.body to the Business class. However, there is no need to copy property by property manually - you can make, for example, a simple copy of req.body to pass as parameter:

```
var b = new Business($.extend({}, req.body));
```

or

```
var b = new Business(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body)));
```

Comment: No, he does not use jQuery. This code is serverside.

Comment: I'm indeed not using jquery, the code if from a node/express backend in JS